# Vector causing huge memory usage

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have a 2D vector which is causing massive memory usage. The vector is supposed to have fixed number of rows and dynamic number of columns.

```
vector < vector < Data >> myVec(257);

struct Data{
uint64_t v1,v2,v3,v4;
int v5,v6; 
};
```

The size of `Data` struct is `40 bytes`.

```
sizeof(Data)
```

While having 62,367,800 elements in `myVec`, my memory usage goes above 11GB. I understand that the memory requirement for the data should be around `(62367800*40) Bytes /(1024^3) ~ 2.32GB` but I fail to understand why the usage gets so high. What are the exact memory requirements of `myVec`?

The sum of capacity of all the inner vectors is `100925440`

I am storing my data in the vector by expanding the vector using `myVec[i].resize(myVec[i].size()+1);`

Also, based on the scenario I am wondering what alternative methods I could use to improve memory usage.

Edit:

So I just tried to pre reserve the capacity and this time I didn't have to call resize function. I stored values using push_back function.  The memory usage is still at least 11GB. The sum of capacity this time was 82500000.

free -m output before running the program:

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31950       3844      28106         66          7        178
-/+ buffers/cache:       3658      28292
Swap:        37631       2521      35110
```

output from free -m while program running (Paused it after insertion):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31950      17246      14704         65          9       3334
-/+ buffers/cache:      13901      18049
Swap:        37631       2521      35110
```

Comment: Define (or find) some `Matrix` class then use it.

Comment: You are potentially reallocating the vector a massive number of times. You should use a smarter "grow" algorithm. Instead of increasing the size by 1 each time, increase it by 2 times the original size. (Or just let the vector class manage its own memory; it does this for you.)

Comment: How are you measuring the actual memory utilized? Where are you getting the 11+ GB metric from?

Comment: @ChristopherCrowe monitoring the memory usage using `free -m`

Comment: If you are using sparse matrix you could use `std::map<std::pair<int,int>, Data> m;` and using it like `m[{x, y}] = value;`

Comment: @CodyGray: If he's using resize, then he is letting the vector manage its own memory.

Comment: Why down voted? I have described the problem in as detailed as I could.

Comment: When you say *While having 62,367,800 elements in `myVec`*, how many elements are in each of the 62,367,800 vectors that are elements of `myVec`?

Comment: @ChristopherCrowe: ??? Why is that comment to me?

Comment: @user2079303 by 62,367,800 elements I mean the sum of myVec.size(i) = 62,367,800 where i is between 0 and 256.

Comment: `vector.resize(vector.size()+1);` does that mean the outer or inner vectors? Maybe should show example of the exact code used for adding elements

Comment: just because he is telling the vector to resize doesn't mean that the memory is being returned to the OS. Most likely, the program is holding it in reserve under the assumption the program will reallocate it (and hence will have some efficiency).

Comment: @4386427 that's inner vectors. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you calculated the sum of `capacity` of all the inner vectors? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/

Comment: @4386427 Yes, I just did. It's 100925440

Comment: That only brings us to ~4G - strange... But as you can see, the `resize` gives you nothing - just let the vector do it by itself. Still you must have another problem..... hmmm

Comment: @4386427 that's something new to me. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If I might ask, what is the more common usage of this data structure going to be? Are there going to be continual writes? Deletions? Arbitrary insertions? Depending on how you plan on using it, `vector` might not be the best choice.

Comment: Is the nature of your program so that you have a reasonable good idea about the number of elements that will end up in each of the inner vectors? If so you could try to reserve the capacity up front, e.g. reserve 10 more elements than expected and let the vector handle the rest (i.e. no resize) - then check how that impacts your total memory usage.

Comment: A potential problem with `resize(n)` is that it leaves an `n-1` block behind. Soon you will have many free memory blocks of sizes `n-1`, `n-2`, `n-3`, etc, but always asking for an `n+1` sized block which doesn't fit in any of those. If you could use `push_back` instead of `resize` and assign, the vector could likely manage memory better.

Comment: If you have a well defined static test data set, you can run it and find the largest of all inner vectors and then reserve that for all inner vectors in a new run.

Comment: @BoPersson - was that comment for me? If so please elaborate as I miss the point :-)

Comment: @438 - No, that was for the OP. Memory fragmentation is a possible reason for what he is seeing.

Comment: Just to make sure - your code never changes the number of inner vector - it is fixed at 257 - correct?

Comment: Good heavens! 2D vectors are bad enough, but for 62,367,800? You're using hundreds of megabytes just for the metadata! You should be storing all your data in a _single_ contiguous block of data; you may implement 2D indexing as a facade on top of this if you like.

Comment: @4386427 the outer vector remains 257. I just tried your suggestion by giving the inner vector fixed capacity using reserve function and inserting values using push_back. This time the sum of capacity became 82500000 but the memory usage was still very high.

Comment: @user994144 - could you post the output from `free -m`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - with only 257 inner vectors how should the metadata go to hundreds of megabytes metadata? Maybe you have the answer, I can't figure out :-)

Comment: @4386427 sure, see the edit.

Comment: @4386427: Direct quote, _"While having 62,367,800 elements in myVec"_. I don't know how the 257 comes into it. Presumably he's expanding from 257 to 62 million for some reason. Either way it's barmy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - that what was I suspected but OP claims that the number of inner vectors is fixed at 257 and the posted code suggests that it is true. If it is true, the overhead is no problem.

Comment: @user994144 - can you post `free -m` before running your program and while the program is running (and all elements inserted in the vector)

Comment: @4386427 see the edit.

Comment: @4386427: Such overhead isn't going to exhaust your RAM, but it's still _way_ more than necessary. 2D vectors = bad almost always

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Agree. What we are trying to figure out is why this approach uses ~10G of mem instead of 2-4G. That is strange and interesting. But it does **not** mean I would use the same method as OP. And I can't see how those 6-8G missing Gs should end up as metadata. Any glue?

Comment: @4386427: Well for a start the method used to determine how much virtual memory is being used by the process is completely wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - If I read this correct the amount of physical memory used increased by 10G. So the amount of virtual memory being used can't be less (probably more). I know from reading many of your answers that you have a lot of knowledge, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @4386427: _"the amount of virtual memory being used can't be less (probably more)"_ You have that backwards :D It certainly can't be more. It can be less because the OS won't necessarily immediately reclaim memory deallocated in a process. I can imagine this coming up a lot with the OP's large and frequent reallocations.

Comment: @4386427: `htop` shows you nothing relating to this. It's actually very hard to measure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - thanks - I guess I need some time to digest your input :-)

Comment: @4386427: I wouldn't pay too much attention to it; I'm not an expert on this topic and may have got something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. Don't call `resize` on the vector. Use `push_back` to add to it. You're constantly leaving behind a block just the tiniest bit too small to fit the enlarged vector.
2. Don't use `free -m` to assess *program* memory usage as it measures *system* physical RAM usage. The relationship between these things is complex and the information is very misleading. Instead, use a tool like `top` or `ps` to show program virtual memory usage and/or resident set size.

Comment: I tried 1 with not much luck. Will give 2 a try and post my observation.

Comment: @user994144 How many elements in the outer vector? How many total inner elements? 10Gb might be reasonable.

Comment: vector < vector < Data >> myVec(257);
myVec[i].reserve(2500000); 

I don't have to resize any more.

Comment: @user994144 - I hope you made a typo - you don't reserve 2.500.000 for each inner vector - do you? That would be all wrong as you only have ~70.000.000 elements in total!

Comment: I do. Because my inner vector could be that long. But reserving all the space in advance is resulting in so much unnecessary space being reserved as the sum of all the inner vectors sizes should be less than 70 million.

Comment: @4386427 I now tried with removing the reserve part and let the program insert by just using push_back. This time Capacity increased to 100925440. This time my VIRT memory came down to 14.3G

Comment: @user994144 - it makes no sense. When you reserved 2.500.000 for each inner vector, your capacity was (at least) 642.500.000 - now you tell it increase to 100.925.440 ! But that is not an increase - it is a huge decrease.

Comment: @4386427 It was 62,367,800, not 642,500,000.

Comment: @user994144 - if you reserve 2,500,000 for each inner vector (as you write in a comment above), the total capacity is 257 x 2,500,000 is  642,500,000. That doesn't match with anything you told so far. Your information doesn't match up.

Comment: @4386427 That matches 24GB perfectly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - It does and it explains everything, except that OP have given other numbers in comments under the question. In the question capacity is 82,500,000 which is not what is mentioned here.